# Loading separate pages in JQTouch

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

Im trying to load a new page when i click on a link.
Its possible to achieve that? i tried to use the load method but it doesnt work, maybe im doing it wrong..

```
        $('.sinistros').click(function(){
            $(document).load('index.html');
        });
```

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `.load()` function is not used to load a new document or page. It is an event listener that fires when the element loads. Basically what this is saying is, listen for a click, and once they click, listen for the document to load. Read more on it [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Try the following instead:

```
    $('.sinistros').click(function(){
        location.href = 'index.html';
    });
```

Comment: Thank u very much..thats one of the reasons i should dig even more in pure Javascript. Another question though: If i want to load a specified div content, how do i do it? ex: location.href = 'index.html?#div'; It doesnt work of course..

Comment: You can't load the content of just a single div. The easiest way to do it is to set up a AJAX service to provide the content of the div. The other way to do it is do an AJAX call to that page, and parse out the div you want. If you need to read up on AJAX, I'd recommend taking a look at some tutorials. http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp